# How to convert a GPG key into a .asc file without knowing the passcode

Tags: gnupg

I have lost the passcode to a GPG keypair, and need to recover it. In the process of doing so I need to convert into a `.asc` file for `gpg2john`. However the GPG cli askes for a password to convert it into the ascii-armored version... which I do not have. Is there anyway for me to get the `.asc` file from just the keys.

I can not use the below command as it requires a password.

```sh
gpg --export-secret-key --armor
```

Note: [recover lost gpg password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020451/recover-lost-gpg-password) doesn't seem have any real answers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (see [recover lost gpg password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020451/recover-lost-gpg-password)), gnupg added code to require a passphrase for export in newer versions. If you install an old, old version, like

```
brew install gnupg@1.4
```

you can then call

```
gpg1 -a --export-secret-keys ID >exportedPrivateKey.asc
```

without having to enter a passphrase.

Needless to say, only use gpg1 for that one task, not for ongoing encryption ;)

Comment: I should add that this worked well for an older key that was created with gpg1 long ago. A newer key, created with gpg2, is not seen by gpg1 at all, so I couldn't export that one.

I believe but have not tested that you could get the gnupg source and remove the password check. My understanding is that it's not technically needed to do the export.